# How to Cut Copy Paste and Select in a 'Only number alowed textbox' using JQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

In a textbox, user can only enter Numbers(0-9), Comma, Dot and Backspace.

We want user to operate (Ctrl +X,Ctrl+V,Ctrl+C, Ctrl+A) in textbox; 
But should not enter V, X, A and C in textbox. How to apply the business logic to following code?

```
function isDecimalNumber(eve, element) {
 var charCode = (eve.which) ? eve.which : event.keyCode
 if (charCode == 44 || charCode == 46 || charCode == 8 || (charCode > 48 && charCode < 57))
  return true; 
 return false;
}
```

Please use this fiddle just for reference: https://jsfiddle.net/jdxn1Lmn/5/

Comment: Hi, if the answer helped you, you can check the check image beside the answer. This will help researchers to identify the best working solution for the question you posted. Good day :)

Answer (score 1):

What you can do is something like this.

Use the utility I created below:

```
  var clipboardUtility = {
      getCopiedText: function (params) {
          var input = params || {},
              e = input.event,
              incomingText;

          if (e) {
              if (e.originalEvent.clipboardData) {
                  incomingText = (e.originalEvent || e).clipboardData.getData('text/plain');
              } else if (window.clipboardData) {
                  incomingText = window.clipboardData.getData('Text');
              }
          }

          return incomingText;
      }
  };
```

and attach your paste event on jQuery

```
    $("#txt-subject-name").bind("paste", onPatseEvent);
```

and put the following code on your paste event:

```
function onPatseEvent(e) {
    var incomingText = clipboardUtility.getCopiedText({
        event: e
    });

    //Regex way of numeric input only
    if (/^\d+$/g.test(incomingText)) {
        e.preventDefault();
            alert('Pasting values that contains non numeric values are not allowed');
    }
},
```